# How to get row number, such that row should contains a specific text in protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber framework.I need to click on a 'td' element in a row of a table.Among the all table rows, i am deciding to click on a row, such that row should contains a specific text(lets say "published").i am able to get that text but the click function is implemented on other column of that row.So i need to take the row number of that text containing so that using this row count i will be able to click on the other column element which having the click function.Below is the html code for one of the table row.

```
<tr class="K7hAcc QwxBBf" for="iBW8sb0" jsshadow="">
  <td class="XgRaPc AB6Eee RdU54d IRKtVe PLK3Id hhyjHe">
    <content class="zRhise">
      <a class="GRgXff sV" href="https://business.google.com/dashboard/l/16047977676197040292">
        <span class="j5emz">Cavender's Boot City</span><br>
        <span class="D0EYxd">303 NW Loop 410, San Antonio, TX 78216, United States</span>
      </a></content></td>
  <td class="XgRaPc AB6Eee RdU54d IRKtVe">
    <content class="zRhise"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="zQoJdc P6t5mb"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 15l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path></svg>
      <span class="StcyZc">Published</span>
    </content></td>
  <td class="XgRaPc AB6Eee RdU54d IRKtVe">
    <content class="zRhise"><div class="ypExpf"></div>
    </content></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <li class="pet">Dog</li>
  <li class="pet">Cat</li>
</ul>
Code
// Returns the li for the dog, but not cat.
var dog = element(by.cssContainingText('.pet', 'Dog'));
```

Refer the above code. Make sure you have the correct CSS and replace `Dog` with Published.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Great thanks..i have implemented below code and its working.
var row=element(by.cssContainingText("table tr","Published"));
row.element(by.css("td:nth-child(2) content")).click();

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath in this case, something like:

```
var yourvariable = element(by.xpath('//span[text()="Published"]/ancestor::td'));
```

PS. It's not CSS code, it's HTML